# Pyspark/SQL: add a flag column like left semi join

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

For example, the data is

```py
customer = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, "Bill Chambers"),
    (1, "Matei Zaharia"),
    (2, "Michael Armbrust")])\
  .toDF("customerid", "name")

order = spark.createDataFrame([
    (0, 0, "Product 0"),
    (1, 1, "Product 1"),
    (2, 1, "Product 2"),
    (3, 3, "Product 3"),
    (4, 1, "Product 4")])\
  .toDF("orderid", "customerid", "product_name")
```

to get customer with order, I can do it with `left semi`

```py
customer.join(order, ['customerid'], "left_semi").show()
```

It can return

[image]

Now for comparison reason, I want to add a flag column instead of directly filtering out some rows. The desired output would look like this:

```py
+----------+----------------+---------+ 
|customerid|            name|has_order| 
+----------+----------------+---------+ 
|         0| Bill Chambers  |     true| 
|         1| Matei Zaharia  |     true| 
|         2|Michael Armbrust|    false| 
+----------+----------------+---------+
```

How can I do it? Is there any elegant way to do it? I tried to search but didn't find things related, maybe I get the wrong key words?

---

Possible to do it with SQL's exist/in?: [Spark replacement for EXISTS and IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861516/spark-replacement-for-exists-and-in#)

Comment: You could use `except` like `join_result.except(customer).withColumn("has_order", lit(False))` and then `union` the result with `join_result.withColumn("has_order", lit(True))`. Or you could select distinct order_id and then do a left join with `customer` then use `when` - `otherwise` with `nvl` to populate `has_order`

Comment: @philantrovert yeah....but that's just much more compleax compare to the `left_semi`'s simplicity.

Comment: @cqcn1991 personally I think join and filter is the better solution, but there's also the option of `union` of `leftsemi` and `leftanti` joins (see my [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50510507/5858851)).

Answer (score 1):

You can do a left join, and use [`pyspark.sql.Column.isNull()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.isNull) to create the `has_order` column based on whether or not the `orderid` columns is not null. Then use `distinct()` to drop the duplicate rows.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
customer.alias("c").join(order.alias("o"), on=["customerid"], how="left")\
    .select(
        "c.*",
        f.col("o.orderid").isNull().alias("has_order")
    )\
    .distinct()\
    .show()
#+----------+----------------+---------+
#|customerid|            name|has_order|
#+----------+----------------+---------+
#|         0|   Bill Chambers|     true|
#|         1|   Matei Zaharia|     true|
#|         2|Michael Armbrust|    false|
#+----------+----------------+---------+
```

---

If you wanted to use something similar to the left-semi join you were working with, you can union the result of left-semi join and a left-anti join:

```python
cust_left_semi = customer.join(order, ['customerid'], "leftsemi")\
    .withColumn('has_order', f.lit(True))
cust_left_semi.show()
#+----------+-------------+---------+
#|customerid|         name|has_order|
#+----------+-------------+---------+
#|         0|Bill Chambers|     true|
#|         1|Matei Zaharia|     true|
#+----------+-------------+---------+

cust_left_anti = customer.join(order, ['customerid'], "leftanti")\
    .withColumn('has_order', f.lit(False))
cust_left_anti.show()
#+----------+----------------+---------+
#|customerid|            name|has_order|
#+----------+----------------+---------+
#|         2|Michael Armbrust|    false|
#+----------+----------------+---------+

cust_left_semi.union(cust_left_anti).show()
#+----------+----------------+---------+
#|customerid|            name|has_order|
#+----------+----------------+---------+
#|         0|   Bill Chambers|     true|
#|         1|   Matei Zaharia|     true|
#|         2|Michael Armbrust|    false|
#+----------+----------------+---------+
```

Comment: OK, I'll try to benchmark these 2 solutions and give you some feedback.

Comment: And, is it possible to achieve the result through SQL with simple solution, as IN/Exist is supported in SQL?

Comment: As shown in the [post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861516/spark-replacement-for-exists-and-in#), there is currently no support for EXISTS/IN in SparkSQL AFAIK.