# Pyspark isin with column in argument doesn't exclude rows

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to exclude rows which doesn't have True value in column Status.

In my opinion this filter( isin( )== False)  structure should solve my problem but it doesn't.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([( "A", "True"), ( "A", "False"), ( "B", "False"), ("C",  "True")], ( "name", "status")) 
df.registerTempTable("df")
df_t = df[df.status == "True"]

from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

df_f = df.filter(df.status.isin(df_t.name)== False)
```

I expect row:

```
B | False
```

any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `isin` doesn't work like that. You need to use a `join`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark replacement for EXISTS and IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861516/spark-replacement-for-exists-and-in)

Answer (score 0):

First, I think in your last statement, you meant to use `df.name` instead of `df.status`.

```
df_f = df.filter(df.status.isin(df_t.name)== False)
```

Second, even if you use `df.name`, it still won't work. 
Because it's mixing the columns (Column type) from two DataFrames, i.e. `df_t` and `df` in your final statement. I don't think this works in pyspark. 
However, you can achieve the same effect using other methods.
If I understand correctly, you want to select 'A' and 'C' first through 'status' column, then select the rows excluding ['A', 'C']. The thing here is to extend the selection to the second row of 'A', which can be achieved by `Window`. See below:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([( "A", "True"), ( "A", "False"), ( "B", "False"), ("C",  "True")], ( "name", "status")) 
df.registerTempTable("df")
# create an auxiliary column satisfying the condition
df = df.withColumn("flag", F.when(df['status']=="True", 1).otherwise(0))
df.show()
# extend the selection to other rows with the same 'name'
df = df.withColumn('flag', F.max(df['flag']).over(Window.partitionBy('name')))
df.show()
#filter is now easy
df_f = df.filter(df.flag==0)
df_f.show()
```