# use corelated subquery in pyspark sql

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, correlated-subquery, apache-spark-2.3

Tab1 Columns `[F,S,E]`

```
F1 S1 R
F1 S2 R2
F1 S3 R1
F2 S1 R2
F2 S4 R4
F1 S4 R
```

Tab2 Columns `[F,S]`

```
F1 S1
F1 S3
F2 S1
F2 S4
```

TAKE ROWS FROM TAB1 FOR ONLY IF F->S RELATION IS PRESENT IN Tab2

RESULT Columns `[F,S,E]`

```
F1 S1 R
F1 S3 R
F2 S4 R4
```

I have the query now, but am not able to get results with pyspark.I am able to run on MySql db.

I tried to use corelated subquery in spark 2.4.3, but this returns 0 rows.

```
Tab1.createOrReplaceTempView("Tab1")

Tab2.createOrReplaceTempView("Tab2")

joined_df = spark.sql(
    """SELECT F, S, E FROM Tab1 
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Tab2 WHERE Tab1.F=Tab2.F AND Tab1.S=Tab2.S)"""
)

joined_df.show(10)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark replacement for EXISTS and IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861516/spark-replacement-for-exists-and-in)

Comment: why not F1 S3 R1. The second row in your output. How come it's F1 S3 R. ?