# How to implement EXISTS condition as like SQL in spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am curious to know, how can i implement sql like exists clause in spark Dataframe way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spark replacement for EXISTS and IN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861516/spark-replacement-for-exists-and-in)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LEFT SEMI JOIN` is equivalent to the `EXISTS` function in Spark.

```
val cityDF= Seq(("Delhi","India"),("Kolkata","India"),("Mumbai","India"),("Nairobi","Kenya"),("Colombo","Srilanka")).toDF("City","Country")
```

[image: df1]

```
val CodeDF= Seq(("011","Delhi"),("022","Mumbai"),("033","Kolkata"),("044","Chennai")).toDF("Code","City")
```

[image: df2]

```
val finalDF= cityDF.join(CodeDF, cityDF("City") === CodeDF("City"), "left_semi")
```

[image: df3]

Comment: Any other way instead of join operation? Since I have too many joins in my Sql query and I don't want to make it more complex using this join syntax. Any other way will be appreciated

Comment: sorry bro :(.. this is what I know..post another question with good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

If the data to be compared is small like a broadcasted list then you can use -

```
df.filter(col("columnName").isin(list...))
```