# Hive Query Subquery inside the filter expresson

Tags: sql, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm using spark sql to create a query. The actual query is bit large in size but the issue I'm getting is the following error

`Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: IN/EXISTS predicate sub-queries can only be used in a Filter: Aggregate`

And the following part of the query is causing the trouble. I am not sure

```
select col1, col2,
sum(case
    WHEN snoozed_until is NULL
        AND hired is NULL
        AND lower(profile_archive_status) = 'true'
        AND profile_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT profile_id
    FROM candidates_feedback f
    WHERE lower(f.a1) LIKE '%no%') THEN
        1
        ELSE 0 END) Archived, 
        sum(case
        WHEN snoozed_until is NULL
            AND hired is NULL
            AND lower(profile_archive_status) = 'true'
            AND profile_id IN (SELECT profile_id FROM candidates_feedback f WHERE lower(f.a1) LIKE '%no%') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Rejected,
from table;
```

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've update the query, I hope its making sense now. Similar kind of thing is here.
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861516/spark-replacement-for-exists-and-in/34866817

Comment: the IN/EXISTS predicates are not allowed in the select projection. the query analyser says it only accpted in the filter. Please try to rework the query

Answer (score 0):

Use left join with sub-query:

```
select col1, col2,
sum(CASE
       WHEN snoozed_until is NULL
        AND hired is NULL
        AND lower(profile_archive_status) = 'true'
        AND p.profile_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
     END) Archived, 
sum(CASE
        WHEN snoozed_until is NULL
            AND hired is NULL
            AND lower(profile_archive_status) = 'true'
            AND p.profile_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END) Rejected
from table t
     left join 
     (SELECT DISTINCT profile_id
        FROM candidates_feedback f
       WHERE lower(f.a1) LIKE '%no%') p on t.profile_id=p.profile_id
```